# Postfix has high precedence than prefix so value of sml2 in given code should be 2 but it's 0. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, operator-precedence, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```
namespace Randomedits
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 2;
            int sml2 = ++x - (x++) ;
            Console.WriteLine(sml2);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
4
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operators):

> Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right. For example, in `F(i) + G(i++) * H(i)`, method `F` is called using the old value of `i`, then method `G` is called with the old value of `i`, and, finally, method `H` is called with the new value of `i`. This is separate from and unrelated to operator precedence.

Applying this to your expression `++x - x++`, we can see that first `++x` is evaluated, then `x++` is evaluated, then the subtraction is evaluated.

A good way of thinking about operator precedence is that operators with higher precedence *bind more tightly* than operators with lower precedence. It's used when working out what expressions a sequence of characters should be parsed as, not the order in which things are evaluated.

For example, in the expression `++ x - x ++`, the operator `++x` binds more tightly than the `-` operator, and the `x++` operator binds more tightly than the `-` operator, so this is parsed as `(++x) - (x++)`. If the `-` operator had higher precedence than the `++x` or `x++` operators, this expression would be parsed as `++(x - x)++` (which wouldn't make much sense).

The fact that `++x` has higher precedence than `x++` doesn't matter here. It *does* matter for the expression `++x++`, which is parsed as `(++x)++` rather than `++(x++)` (and raises a compiler error because the operator `x++` can't be applied to the expression `(++x)`).

Once you've used the rules of operator precedence to figure out that `++ x - x ++` should be parsed as `(++x) - (x++)`, the quoted rules above apply, and the operands of the `-` expression are evaluated left-to-right.